# How to oneline two variables via echo?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I try to search for files and seperate path and version as variable because each will be needed later for creating a directory and to unzip a .jar in desired path.

```
file=$(find /home/user/Documents/test/ -path *.jar)
version=$(echo "$file" | grep -P -o '[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]')
path=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\(.*\)[/].*/\1/') 
newpath=$(echo "${path}/${version}")
echo "$newpath"
```

result

```
> /home/user/Documents/test/gb0500
> /home/user/Documents/test/gb0500 /home/user/Documents/test/gb0500
> /home/user/Documents/test /home/user/Documents/test/1.3.2.0
> 1.3.2.1
> 1.3.2.2
> 1.2.0.0
> 1.3.0.0
```

It's hilarious that it's only working at one line. 
what else I tried:

```
file=$(find /home/v990549/Dokumente/test/ -path *.jar)
version=$(grep -P -o '[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]')
path=$(sed 's/\(.*\)[/].*/\1/')

while read $file
do
  echo "$path$version"
done
```

I have no experience in scripting. Thats what I figured out some days ago. I am just practicing and trying to make life easier.

find output:

```
/home/user/Documents/test/gb0500/gb0500-koetlin-log4j2-web-1.3.2.0-javadoc.jar
/home/user/Documents/test/gb0500/gb0500-koetlin-log4j2-web-1.3.2.1-javadoc.jar
/home/user/Documents/test/gb0500/gb0500-koetlin-log4j2-web-1.3.2.2-javadoc.jar
/home/user/Documents/test/gb0500-co-log4j2-web-1.2.0.0-javadoc.jar
/home/user/Documents/test/gb0500-commons-log4j2-web-1.3.0.0-javadoc.jar
```

Comment: There are so many problems with this script I don't know where to start

Comment: At least show us an excerpt from `find`'s output so we can try helping

Comment: There are a bunch of things here that need to be quoted to work right. Try running it through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for suggestions.

Comment: Ah well... I see.. I had it already quoted once, but I forgot to add it back, while testing other things. So yes, you are right. My mistake.

Comment: Is version part always between `web-` and `-javadoc.jar`, or its position in the name, or strings around it, is arbitrary?

Comment: The Version is the only thing thats always identical in length and format. I just took a single .jar file and edited for experimental purpose. So the name is always different. 
My goal is to to watch if a new .jar file gets uploaded, to unzip it in the same directory as the .jar file is located. The new directory has the version in the name, because I need to symlink it for our repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the both variables `version` and `path` are newline-separated, how about:

```
file=$(find /home/user/Documents/test/ -path *.jar)
version=$(echo "$file" | grep -P -o '[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]')
path=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\(.*\)[/].*/\1/')
paste -d "/" <(echo "$path") <(echo "$version")
```

Result:

```
/home/user/Documents/test/gb0500/1.3.2.0
/home/user/Documents/test/gb0500/1.3.2.1
/home/user/Documents/test/gb0500/1.3.2.2
/home/user/Documents/test/1.2.0.0
/home/user/Documents/test/1.3.0.0
```

BTW I do not recommend to store multiple filenames in a single variable
as a newline-separated variable due to several reasons:

- Filenames may contain a newline character.
- It is not easy to manipulate the values of each line.
  For instance you could simply say
  the third line as `path=${file%/*}` if `file` contains just one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps indeed. This shows me, that I wasn't that far away from my wanted result. I've just never used "paste", because i haven't heard from it yet.

Comment: Yes, you were almost there. As you'll see the top three lines are unchanged. It's my pleasure if it helped. I hope you'll enjoy bash scripting.